# Facebook API & Twitter API

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I have a little area on my dashboard on my CMS where I want it to use a facebook fan page API AND twitter API to collect the last 6 total updates so it puts them together and gets the 6 most recent updates/statuses and list them is this possible to mix them like this?

Any other ideas?

I'm not seeing any tutorials on this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, yes it's possible. You can even do this without server side, just with javascript.

Comment: Is there a javascript I need to download this that works with code igniter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Facebook page posts, you can grab them (assuming you are an admin of the page) via:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/feed

As explained here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed

This will return a JSON array of posts with a timestamp. I'm not too familiar with Twitters API, but they'll very likely return a similar JSON array. You can then use some simple sorting-fu to combine those two arrays and then sort them by the timestamps.